# Why was std::bit_cast added, if reinterpret_cast could do the same?

Tags: c++, c++20, language-design, type-alias, bit-cast

[`std::bit-cast`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0476r2.html) was introduced in the C++20 standard.

I know that `reinterpret_cast` is not suitable for this job due to [type aliasing rules](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast#Type_aliasing). However, why did they choose not to extend `reinterpret_cast` to treat the object like it bit sequence representation and preferred to give this functionality as a new language construct?

Comment: In what way are you suggesting that `reinterpret_cast` be extended? That is, what would code that uses this hypothetically look like?

Comment: @NicolBolas: How about allowing `reinterpret_cast` to do this: `float x = 1.0f; reinterpret_cast<unsigned int>(x);`.

Comment: I was thinking exactly like @geza suggested

Comment: @geza: `reinterpret_cast` already has a defined meaning for that, so that would be changing the semantics of reinterpret_cast, not extending it.

Comment: @ChrisDodd: I don't think that's true. What meaning has it currently?

Comment: @geza `reinterpret_cast<unsigned>(1.0f) == 1U;` -- it does a float->int conversion.

Comment: @ChrisDodd: no, that conversion is ill-formed currently.

Comment: This was in fact [proposed](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_closed.html#944) long ago.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Well, there is one obvious reason: because it wouldn't do everything that `bit_cast` does. Even in the C++20 world where we can allocate memory at compile time, `reinterpret_cast` is forbidden in `constexpr` functions. One of the explicit goals of `bit_cast` is to be able to do these sorts of things at compile-time:

> Furthermore, it is currently impossible to implement a `constexpr` bit-cast function, as `memcpy` itself isn’t `constexpr`. Marking the proposed function as `constexpr` doesn’t require or prevent `memcpy` from becoming `constexpr`, but requires compiler support. This leaves implementations free to use their own internal solution (e.g. LLVM has a `bitcast` opcode).

Now, you could say that you could just extend this specific usage of `reinterpret_cast` to `constexpr` contexts. But that makes the rules complicated. Instead of simply knowing that `reinterpret_cast` can't be used in `constexpr` code period, you have to remember the specific forms of `reinterpret_cast` that can't be used.

Also, there are practical concerns. Even if you wanted to go the `reinterpret_cast` route, `std::bit_cast` is a library function. And it's always easier to get a library feature through the committee than a language feature, even if it would receive some compiler support.

Then there's the more subjective stuff. `reinterpret_cast` is generally considered an inherently dangerous operation, indicative of "cheating" the type system in some way. By contrast, `bit_cast` is not. It is generating a new object as if by copying its value representation from an existing one. It's a low-level tool, but it's not a tool that messes with the type system. So it would be strange to spell a "safe" operation the same way you spell a "dangerous" one.

Indeed, if you did spell them the same way, it starts raising questions as to why this is reasonably well-defined:

```
float f = 20.4f;
int i = reinterpret_cast<int>(f);
```

But this is somehow bad:

```
float f = 20.4f;
int &i = reinterpret_cast<int &>(f);
```

And sure, a language lawyer or someone familiar with the strict aliasing rule would understand why the latter is bad. But for the lay person, if it is fine to use `reinterpret_cast` to do a bit-conversion, it is unclear why it is wrong to use `reinterpret_cast` to convert pointers/references and interpret an existing object as a converted type.

Different tools should be spelled differently.

Comment: The second of your latter forms should be defined in cases where all use of `i` occurs before the next time that storage is accessed or addressed in conflicting fashion (writes conflict with reads or writes; reads do not conflict with reads) via means not derived from `i`, or execution reaches the start of a function or bona fide loop body wherein that will occur.  The "Strict Aliasing" rule was intended to avoid requiring compilers to be pessimistic about things they can't see--not to encourage them to ignore things they can.

Comment: Regarding *"`reinterpret_cast` is generally considered an inherently dangerous operation"*... I think this doesn't account for what's probably the most common use case I see for `reinterpret_cast`, which is something like `reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(ptr)`. That's no more dangerous or "cheating" of the type system than `static_cast<unsigned char *>(static_cast<void *>(ptr))`.

Comment: @user541686: That isn't allowed in constexpr code either. You can `constexpr` `bit_cast` to a byte array though. And no, that's not more dangerous; it's just longer.

Answer (score -10):

There is a fundamental mismatch between the high level language nature of modern, strict interpretation of the C and C++ language standards by compilers and the notion that you can use `reinterpret_cast` to reinterpret a bunch of bytes as another objects. Note that the so called "strict aliasing" rule in most cases cannot even be used to disqualify any attempt at reinterpreting bytes as the code wouldn't have defined behavior in the first place: `reinterpret_cast<float*>(&Int)` isn't even a pointer to a float object, it's a pointer to an integer that happens to have the wrong type. You can't dereference it as there is no float object created at that place; if there was one, its lifetime wouldn't have started; and if its lifetime had started, it would be uninitialized.

Bytes that happen to represent a valid float bit pattern just can't be interpreted as such if you don't have a proper float object here.

A valid non null pointer isn't just a typed value of a start address of an area that happens to be properly aligned; **a non null valid pointer points to a particular object** (or one past the end of an array or a trivial "array" of one object).

I don't even see the "strict aliasing" sanctioned scalar reinterpretation casts (signed/unsigned mix) as possibly valid, as non signed (resp. unsigned) integer object exists at that address (and the compiler obviously cannot use the unsigned (resp. signed) original value either).

Either way, C++ has a broken design because it's a mix of different languages (some very low level some very high level) and is badly broken.

Comment: "*the so called "strict aliasing" rule in most cases cannot even be used to disqualify any attempt at reinterpreting bytes as the code wouldn't have defined behavior in the first place*" ... what? It's the strict-aliasing rule that *causes* that code to be UB. Without that rule, the standard would be incomplete, because there wouldn't be a statement about the behavior of what that would be. There's a difference between "this is UB" and "the standard is underspecified in this area."

Comment: @NicolBolas Who said the std needed to be complete? How is it complete now? What does it mean to dereference a reinterpret_casted pointer in any case? If it's OK to cast to `char*` why not to `short*` or `float*`? If it's OK to use traditionally `memcpy` and recently `bit_cast` why isn't it OK to dereference a casted pointer?

Comment: @NicolBolas In C, where is the behavior of `memcpy` by a `FILE` over another one defined? Are all calls to `memcpy` either fully defined or explicitly made UB?

Comment: ”`reinterpret_cast<float*>(&Int)` isn't even a pointer to a float object, it's a pointer to an integer that happens to have the wrong type. You can't dereference it as there is no float object created at that place”, despite all the downvotes this was the answer that I actually understand, thank you, but I disagree with rest of statements you made

Comment: U do be getting destroyed on this vote. Sorry m8