# Converting a templated data into another templated data

Tags: c++, alignment, reinterpret-cast, type-punning

I have a method returning a templated class and taking as argument another templated class such as :

```cpp
template <class T, class U>
T caster(U* u)
{
    return reinterpret_cast<T>(u);  
}
```

Compiling with an ARM compiler, i get a cast-align error returned by my compiler which understandable because in my example bellow, char and int do not have the same alignment. As i know that reinterpret_cast is not that such of a good practice,
i tried the following changes :

```cpp
template <class T, class U>
T caster(U* u)
{
    T tmp;
    std::memcpy(&tmp, u, sizeof(U));
    return tmp;
}

int main()
{
    int32_t test = 50000;
    auto tmp = caster<char, int32_t>(&test);
    return 0;
}
```

But this time i get a stack smashing detected error which is equivalent i believe to a kind of overflow.

What am I doing wrong ? Based on 2 unknown types, how can i properly cast U to T taking into account alignment ?

Comment: `int32_t` is larger than a `char`, you copy 4 bytes into a location that is only declared to contain one. It seems like you aren't certain what the result of this cast should be, hence you keep hitting bugs. Do you want the MSB copied or the LSB? What about the case where the target is larger than the source? And why do you need to transfer bytes around anyway, why not do a regular cast of values?

Comment: your first  `caster` is not casting a `U` to a `T`. `reinterpret_cast<T>(u);` attempts to make a `T` from a `U*`

Comment: why do you need this? Generally you cannot bytewise copy objects between two arbitrarty types and expect to get a proper object.

Comment: The first caster method is a piece of code i inherited which was tested on some non-ARM architecture, hence, some architecture where alignment seems to be managed correctly. I need to run this on ARM compiler, that's why I tried not to use the reinterpret_cast

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```cpp
> T tmp;
> std::memcpy(&tmp, u, sizeof(U));
> return tmp;
> ```

The obvious issue here is that you're copying `sizeof(U)` bytes into `T`, even though `T` may be smaller or larger.

- if `T` is larger, it's possible that some bytes of `tmp` are left indeterminate
- if `T` is smaller, you write past the end of `tmp`

  - stack smashing happens where `T = char` and `U = int32_t` because three bytes are written past the end of `tmp`

If anything, it should be `sizeof(T)` or `sizeof(tmp)`:

```cpp
template <class T>
T caster(void* memory) {
    T tmp;
    // It's still possible that we cannot read sizeof(T) bytes from memory,
    // but that's on the caller, and at least we never smash the stack.
    std::memcpy(&tmp, memory, sizeof(T));
    return tmp;
}
```

Notice that what you're making here is a poor-man's [`std::bit_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/bit_cast).
It's one of the ways to do type punning in modern C++.
`reinterpret_cast` virtually never is.

#### See also

- [What is the modern, correct way to do type punning in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67636231/5740428)
- [Why was std::bit_cast added, if reinterpret_cast could do the same?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53401654/5740428)